# Android SQLite Alter table rename not commit

Tags: android, database, sqlite, commit

Thanks in advance.

I need to reestructure my database in the new version of my app, and then I use onUpgrade method in my SQLiteOpenHelper class for this purpose.

Well, I need to rename some columns, and how it is not possible in sqlite I decided to create another table, import all data and then delete the old table and rename de new table. All in "onUpgrade" method... well, at the end of the method I need to upload the database to a server, when I walk thought tables I found that cursor returns nullpointer because it not found the new fields, but in fact when I go to de file explorer in DDMS and view the database from my phone I see that fields are inside.
It seems that changes not commit, but I use databasetransaction for this purpose.

What I do wrong?

My code in onupgrade seems like that:

```
public void onUpgrade(final SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

if(oldVersion==22 && newVersion==23){

try {
   db.beginTransaction();

   db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE unidades2 (uuid text, nombre TEXT)");

   c=db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM unidades",null);
   c.moveToFirst();
   while(!c.isAfterLast()){
         auxuuid=new uuid().toString();
         db.execSQL("INSERT INTO unidades2(uuid, nombre) VALUES (?,?)",new String[] {auxuuid,c.getString(1)});
         c.moveToNext();
   }
   c.close();
   db.execSQL("DROP TABLE unidades");
   db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE unidades2 RENAME TO unidades");

   db.setTransactionSuccessful();
}
finally db.endTransaction();

}
}
```

And then walking through unidades table whith a cursor, and do:

```
try {
   db.beginTransaction();

   Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM unidades",null);
   cursor.moveToFirst();
   int hasuuid= cursor.getColumnIndex("uuid");
   cursor.close();

   [Code uploading database in JSON]

   db.setTransactionSuccessful();
}
finally db.endTransaction();
```

hasuuid its -1.

Please help me!! Thanks a lot.

Comment: Your description implies that the database was upgraded, but not uploaded.

Comment: Oh well... I did not explain properly, I will edit my answer with "no-significative" code. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One issue that might cause the problem though it's not apparent in the snippets you posted: `onUpgrade()` is already run inside a transaction. sqlite itself does not support nested transactions. The Android wrapper on top adds partial support so that nested transactions are only committed or rolled back once the outermost transaction is committed or rolled back. The outermost transaction in this case being the one set up before `onUpgrade()` was called. So when you think you commit, no actual commit is performed on sqlite database level.

Comment: Mmm... interesting... I think that could be the solution, let me test it.

Comment: Yes! that is my error! Then I do the rename at the end of onupgrade, and I do the upload based on the new unidades2 table. Thanks a lot!!